# springboot configuration redis serialization

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, redis

[Why is the error "Could not autowire. No beans of 'RedisConnectionFactory' type found" reported here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axW3T.png)

Serialization doesn't work

I used the new way to inject the object and it didn't solve the problem：

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
@Resource
private RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<Object,Object> redisTemplate(){
    RedisTemplate<Object,Object> redisTemplate=new RedisTemplate<>();
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class);
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);

    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);

    
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);

    
    redisTemplate.setStringSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you try my answer? And please give feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was implementing redis server I solved this issue by writing code like this

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "redisTemplate")
  @Primary
  public <T> RedisTemplate<String, T> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RedisTemplate<String, T> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    om.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(om));
    template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(om));
    return template;
  }
}
```

This code may be little different from your requirements, but I think if you look closely you can modified according with your needs.

Comment: Still there will be a prompt "Could not autowire. No beans of 'RedisConnectionFactory' type found"

Comment: I think it is not an issue. Try to run your app. In my application I also got red allert but it works.

Comment: And try to use `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` and `ObjectMapper`

Comment: The serialization mode configuration is successful, thank you very much!!!

Comment: In fact, it is not the problem of the code itself, I have two modules, RedisConfig is in module A, and the test code is in module B. The reason is that the directory structure of module A is not standardized, so that RedisConfig.java cannot be loaded, so the serialization rules of the configuration are not effective.
But still thank you very much for your answer, I'm a newbie, my reputation is less than 15 and I can't upvote it.